# Router v6. 'useBlocker' and 'usePrompt ' are not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

It seems react-router-dom v6.0.2 removed 'useBlocker' and 'usePrompt' (or rename it). How to do the same thing again?

I just want to warn the user when they leave a page.

Comment: Please read this [discussion](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139) on GitHub for details. TL;DR; they removed it, they will add it eventually to v6, stay on v5 if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we are still waiting...

Meanwhile there are libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-prompt for those who need these removed features in React Router v6.